# Java, C++, NIO, mmaped buffer, synchronization

Tags: java, c++, locking, nio, mmap

Exposition:

I am on Linux / Mac.

Part of my code is in Java, part of my code is in C++.

They both have the same file mmapped for fast communication.

I want to synchronize the Java & C++ code.

I know the following:

1) given two threads in Java, I can use Locks / monitors.

2) given one piece of code in Java, one in C++, I can have them synchronize over tcp/ip

3) given two pieces of C++ code, that have mmaped an area of memory, I can have them synchronize using gcc's compare_and_swap on a integer in the mmaped region.

Question:

Given that part of my code is in Java, part of my code is in C++, can I somehow do (3) -- does the JVM support some type of atomic compare & swap ? So both my Java & C++ code can use this integer as a lock of sorts?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=atomic+java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a small C/C++ library that only purpose is to sync with your C++ code (using conventional IPC sync objects). Then you could would this library from your java process using JNI.

Comment: This solution is so simple; yet I never thought of it. However, this seems awfully expensive (a JNI call) to do just this. Is there no cheaper way?

Comment: why expensive? How would CAS be implemented any differently if it was built into the API? Java has CAS through cmpxchg on intel, but I don't think you can specify the mem location to something else but a java variable.

Comment: JVMs (and CLRs) do JITing, so you have straight assembly language calls from JITted Java via JNI to C all the way without any OS calls slowing you down. I'd suggest trying it and actually measure the overhead you incur instead of guessing.